# Activity error message on simulator

Tags: actions-on-google

When trying to use the Actions on Google simulator,

I get "Please turn on Voice & Audio Activity, Web & App Activity, and Device Information permissions for your Google Account".

I have enabled all three in that page https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols and still get the error message

Answer (score -1):

Confirm that you are logged in using the same account. One way to confirm this is to use an incognito browser window to log into the simulator and your activity controls.